# Objective-C initial values of created C-array

Tags: c, objective-c, arrays, memset

I create an array, similar to classic C (not NSArray or one of it's children) - something like `BOOL i[5];`. And I want to make all its values to be equal to NO.

First of all, I didn't found any information about initial values of such arrays (I know that in classic C they will be undefined, but don't know exactly about Objective-C. I found info about classes and its inner data [after allocation, without initialization], but not about simple data types).

And the second, if I should set array values manually - should I use `memset(...);` or something different?

To prevent possible questions... I want to use this construction as array of temporary boolean flags and don't think that it is proved to use something like NSArray here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that `BOOL i[5]` is an ivar of an ObjC class, its content will be initialized (`memset`-ed) to 0.

As described in the [`+alloc` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/alloc):

> ... memory for all other instance variables is set to `0`.

---

To set the array to all NO in other situations, you could use

```
memset(i, 0, sizeof(i));
```

Comment: Yes. And if it's not you can explicitly `memset` it to zero to for `NO` as the default.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is 0-ed instead of undef like in C, a proper initialization should set all values explicitly since you can't know if NO is 0 (it is, but hypotethically...!), so simply:

```
for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) i[j] = NO;
```

could do the job.